# How to fill-down concatenate formula in Excel changing the range

Tags: vba, excel

First post in stackoverflow, hope it works :)
I need to put some information in Excel regarding the text from some jurisdiction (laws, decrees,etc). I have several documents with thousands of lines each. With a OCR processor I was able to put this in an Excel worksheet.
What I want to do now is to get the whole information from each article/paragraph in one single cell.
The data would like this

```
1  Rawdata      ExtractArticle     Result
2  Article 1:    =LEFT(A2,7)        =CONCATENATE((TRANSPOSE(A2:A7))
3  Lorem ipsum
4  Dolor sit
5  amet,
6  consectetur 
7  adipiscing elit
8  Article 2:    =LEFT(A8,7)       =CONCATENATE((TRANSPOSE(A8:A11))
9  ed do eiusmod 
10 tempor incididunt 
11 ut labore
(...)
N-3  Article 100:  =LEFT(A(N-3),7)   =CONCATENATE((TRANSPOSE(A(N-3),A(N-1))
N-2  quo voluptas 
N-1  nulla pariatur?"
```

What I want to do, basically is to extend this formula all over A:A, that is, concatenating the text in between each time the word "Article" appears in the first characters, which will mean the beginning of the article of a law.

I've tried to calculate the blank spaces inbetween each "Article" word, however, with TRANSPOSE this doesn't seem to work. I also thought of using a trick to get the blank spaces between the word in "article", but I can't see how to make this to work out.

The problem, as I see it is that the range of each "article" is variable, so filling down any formula would not work because it would use the same extension for the initial range

Any help would be highly appreciated. I hope my problem makes any sense, in case it doesn't please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Good start - and welcome to StackExchange. Just wondering what is the purpose of the second column "ExtractArticle"? I think you could do this with a simple loop in VBA - extract and concatenate all the articles into concurrent cells on the second Sheet

Comment: For future reference, to make a table on here more readable you can use this tool (created by someone on here): http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ExtractArticle` column change the formula to:

```
=IF(LEFT(A3,7)="Article",A2,A2&" " &B3)
```

Put this in B2 and copy down.

Then in C2 put:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,7)="Article",B2,"")
```

You can hide the B column and only see the results.

[image]

Comment: Scott, this is such a simple yet amazing answer to my request. I really appreciate it. Thank you!